# Metaio AR apps flagged in Google Play with OpenSSL issue

Tags: augmented-reality, metaio

I notice Google Play has flagged my AR apps developed in metaio with this message:

> Security alert
>
> Your app is using a version of OpenSSL containing a security vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Centre article for details, including the deadline for fixing the vulnerability.
>
> Security alert
>
> Your application has an unsafe implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please see the alerts page for more information."

I'm hoping it's an easy fix, such as replacing DLL files. Seems I have till July 11th to sort it.

Anyone had this problem and resolved?

Thanks

PS. I use metaio creator, output to arel, copy that output into an app folder template I created which I run through Android Studio/Xcode to generate the final build.

Comment: Seems I have the Same problem

Comment: So far I've only been able to identify Metaio using OpenSSL version 1.0.1h which is considered vulnerable.

Comment: Has anybody fixed this issue? Is there any place where we can get the metaiosdk and recompile it with the latest openssl?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @MinaSamy Unfortunately not. I switched over to Unity development.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for alternatives, Wikitude came up with a fix a few days ago: http://www.wikitude.com/blog-sdk-update-openssl-upgrade/

Cheers!

Wikitude team